# Why is jquery has selector not returning false?

Tags: jquery

I have the following html:

```
<div class="switch has-switch">
    <div class="switch-animate switch-on">
        <input id="completed" type="checkbox" data-toggle="switch" data-shopify="data shopify" data-order="order number" class="ct-primary completed" value="0"><span class="switch-left">DONE</span>
        <label for="completed">&nbsp;</label><span class="switch-right">NOT</span></div>
</div>
```

The above html is repeated 8 times in an html page I have.  I'm trying to check if the class input is present.

I have an array like so:

```
const tags = ['completed', 'printing', 'proofing'];
```

I then try to loop over the tags and check each element that has .switch

```
function switches(tags) {

  tags.forEach((item) => {
    $('.switch').each(function () {
      const thisEl = $( this ).find('.switch-animate');

      if(thisEl.has(`#${item}`)) {
        thisEl.removeClass( 'switch-off' );
        thisEl.addClass( 'switch-on' );
      }

    });
  });

}
```

My problem is that it's not working meaning when has is NOT present it still gives does not give me a false.  I would expect a false if thisEl didn't have the item.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Id Must be unique over the whole page. So you must nor repeat the same I’d 8 times or you will have undefined behavior

Comment: $(this) represents window object, try arrow function for using 'this' keyword

Comment: Not in this setting $(this) represents the first selector @Masood

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.has()` will return object (As mentioned by [@Fred Stark in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66899151/9695286)). You should be using `.length` of returned object.

```
if (thisEl.has(`#${item}`).length > 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `has` returns a jquery object for chaining. And objects are always truthy, so your `if` will always run the true branch.

Why? Because the purpose of `has` is to reduce a set of selected elements to a smaller set that matches the query.

See: https://api.jquery.com/has/

What you want is something that returns true or false like `$.contains`

see: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/